# Show 'saving...' message with js/jQuery and then redirect to page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, fadeout

I'm trying to show a `saving....` message upon clicking an asp button on my page.

I have most of it working however the `fadeOut` isn't working for me, the message will flash on the screen, then disappear and the redirect will occur.

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input[id$='btnSaveBanners']").click(function () {

         var elem = $('#save-msg');
         elem.toggle();
         elem.fadeOut(3000);

         setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/Admin/Orders/ViewAll.aspx"; }, 5000);
        });
 });
```

And the element defined on my page:

```
<span id="save-msg" style="display:none;">Saved...</span>
```

I thought maybe the call to `toggle()` was interfereing with the animation somehow so I tried removing the `style` attribute to clear the `display:none;` which didn't help at all. I'm using `jQuery 1.7.2` and `jQuery UI 1.7.2`.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpv4B/3/) of the problem which **works** using the exact same code yet when running locally the `Saved...` message just flashes on screen and then the redirect occurs.

Any suggestions on something else to try?

Comment: **If it works in the example** then it's pretty **unlikely we find where error is**. If you can't remove parts of original code to make it more close to the example (until it'll work) then I would check if other event handlers exist (of if it's a submit button) and if setTimeout code works (log to console).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give these a try and come back later

Comment: @Adriano I think the issue is that the `<span>` is within an `UpdatePanel` as removing it from this section sees everything working fine. Do you know of any reasons why it would cause this issue? I may just move it out of the panel and position it in the right spot.

Comment: It's a submit button, it'll refresh page immediately. Don't make it a typ="submit" and perform it manually (with yourFormId.submit(), for example, or via Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

Try fadeOut callback method. Like shown below.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$='btnSaveBanners']").click(function () {
            var elem = $('#save-msg');
            elem.toggle();
            elem.fadeOut(3000, function () {
                setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "/Admin/Orders/ViewAll.aspx"; }, 5000);
            });
        });
    })
```